# Assistance required with basic Rock, Paper, Scissors game

Tags: php

I'm new to php and have been struggling to get my rock, paper, scissors game to work! I know what I'm trying to do but just can't get my head aound where I've gone wrong......it works for rock but for paper and scissors I'm getting two outputs!!Please help a novice out...thanks!!
P.S I know there are much slicker ways of doing this!!

```
<?php

 // user enters a value R P or S - NEED TO RETURN A COUPLE OF 
 TIMES AFTER, not sure why?
 echo "What do you select - R for rock, P for paper or S for 
 scissors?\n"; 
   $input= 
   $R  = stream_get_line(STDIN, 1, "\n"); 
   $P = stream_get_line(STDIN, 1, "\n");
   $S = stream_get_line(STDIN, 1, "\n");
 //program converts the value into Rock, Paper or Scissors
switch ($input) {
case 'R' :
case 'r':
echo $R = "You selected Rock\n" ;
break;
case 'P' :
case 'p':
echo $P = "You selected Paper\n" ;
break;
case 'S' :
case 's':
echo $S = "You selected Scissors\n" ;
break;
}
//computer generates a random value 0,1,2 & converts to R P or S
echo "\nComputer is now making its selection....\n"; 

//$options = ('Rock=0, Paper=1, Scissors=2');
$output = (rand(0,2) );
echo $output; 

if ($output== 0)
{
echo  "\nComputer Selected Rock\n"; //goto Rock;
}
elseif ($output==1) 
{
echo "\nComputer Selected Paper\n"; //goto Paper;
}
elseif ($output==2) 
{
echo "\nComputer Selected Scissors\n"; //goto Scissors;
}
//compare user and computers choise
Rock:
if ($R && $output===0)//.($P && $output==1),($S && $output==2))
{
echo "\nITS A DRAW";
}
elseif ($R && $output===1)//.($P && $output==2).($S && 
$output==0))
{
echo "\nCOMPUTER WINS";
}
elseif ($R && $output===2)//.($P && $output==0).($S && 
$output==1))
{
echo "\nYOU WIN";
}
Paper:
if ($P && $output===1) 
{
echo "\nITS A DRAW";
}
elseif ($P && $output===2) 
{
echo "\nCOMPUTER WINS";
}
elseif ($P && $output===0) 
{
echo "\nYOU WIN";
}
Scissors:
if  ($S && $output===2) 
{
echo "\nITS A DRAW";
}
elseif ($S && $output===0) 
{
echo "\nCOMPUTER WINS";
}
elseif ($S && $output===1) 
{
echo "\nYOU WIN";
}
```

Comment: Apart from that I doubt that you actually get three values by calling `stream_get_line(STDIN, 1, "\n")` three times (assuming the user only makes one input?), what is that part that assigns those values to $R, $P and $S good for anyway? Considering that you overwrite these in the following switch statement anyway, if the $input variable matches that letter.

Comment: I know what you are saying and I need to make it tidier.....but how do i compare the user input with the computer choice without some kind of variable......?? (I am VERY new to php, as in about 3 weeks)

Answer (score 1):

You should inicialize $R, $P and $S to false first. Then read user input 1x into $input.
The rest of the script seams to be ok.

```
<?php
$R = $P = $S = false;
$input= stream_get_line(STDIN, 1, "\n");
```

Comment: Thank you, thank you, thank you!!! It now seems to work perfectly!! I know its not the best way but its been causing me a headache, I'm now going to work on a slicker method.

Answer (score 0):

> `// user enters a value R P or S - NEED TO RETURN A COUPLE OF TIMES AFTER, not sure why?`

because

> `$input=`
>   `$R  = stream_get_line(STDIN, 1, "\n");`
>   `$P = stream_get_line(STDIN, 1, "\n");`
>   `$S = stream_get_line(STDIN, 1, "\n");`

You're calling `stream_get_line()` three times so your script wants three lines of input.

Also, I'm not sure if this was intended, but you're getting your user input seemingly purely by chance as `$input = $R = stream_get_line()` stores the first user input in `$R` *and* `$input`.
I'd suggest only doing `$input = stream_get_line()` and nothign else.

Then in your switch/case block you do e.g. `echo $R = "...";` and further down you do `if ($R && ...)`.
Evaluating strings as booleans is not recommended.
I would recommend something like

```
$R = $P = $S = false; // initialize all variables to false
switch ($input)
{
    case "R":
        $R = true; // set selected variable to true
        echo "You have selected Rock\n";
        break;
    // ...
}
```

Finally, you seem to be using jump marks to comment your code.

> `Rock:`
>   `if ( ...`

While this doesn't cause any problems (yet), it's generally considered bad style to abuse language features for documentation purposes.
These should become comments:

```
// Rock
if ( ...
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I've tidied up the start and initialised the variables to false and it seems to be working!